# Embedding a Paypal Form in the website

Tags: paypal

I've created this great looking paypal donate template for the charity I work for, using PayPal's tools:

[image]

But it I can't seem to embedd it into a website. Instead I'm given the code to make this button:

[image]

which links to the page I want.  I'd like to save the user and extra click (and give a description of what the different amounts do). How can I embedd a paypal donation form within the website?

Comment: Have you contacted PayPal tech support?

Comment: I'll admit I haven't - I have a really negative mindset about the odds of getting good support there...